# asp.net mvc C# List<> Remove

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this

```
  var RadioMetaKey=((IEnumerable<SepiaWEB.Models.Jobs.JobsMeta>)ViewData["JobMeta"]).Where(m=>m.vcr_JobMetaKey==JobsMeta.vcr_JobMetaKey);   

var a=ViewData["JobMeta"]. as List<SepiaWEB.Models.Jobs.JobsMeta>;

a. RemoveAll(RadioMetaKey);  //not working
```

Is there a way i can use RadioMetaKey to remove from a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a Predicate to [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
var radioMetaKey=((IEnumerable<SepiaWEB.Models.Jobs.JobsMeta>)ViewData["JobMeta"])
    .Where(m=>m.vcr_JobMetaKey==JobsMeta.vcr_JobMetaKey);   

var a= ViewData["JobMeta"]. as List<SepiaWEB.Models.Jobs.JobsMeta>;
a.RemoveAll(x=> radioMetaKey.Contains(x));
```